# How to properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged? - C# MVVM WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm

Where to properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged? In Model or ViewModel? And how do you do that having a 1-to-many relationship between two Models?

Comment: First you do a little research.  Then you learn that MVVM is different in winforms than it is in wpf.  Then you prototype a little.  Then you win.  That's what a developer would do.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you do implement this on property setter.

for more info check this link 
[How to: Implement Property Change Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So Arman Nagaepetian, I'm using a base class for OnPropertyChanged, but I have doubts in two things. First is which (Model or ViewModel) is the correct one to use onPropertyChanged? I have seen use in both but I do not know which is the correct or the best form. Second, is it how I pull a list of children from the parent class (one-to-many relationship) using the ObservableCollection?

Comment: For example, can I trigger the Model directly from the form or do I always have to use the ViewModel?

Comment: Please don't link to an external site (even Microsoft) unless it is to support information already in your answer. The sentence "Normally you do implement this on property setter." does not adequately answer this question.

Comment: This should be a comment if you are not going to take the time to illustrate the solution

Answer (score 0):

Jitendra Aanadani,
I would add the implementation in your view-model , your model is suppose to be a simple class (poco). I don't really know what you mean by "pull a list of children"  but in my opinion if you need to get some additional data you should have a repository or some kind of service class which will provide you that Data.

I hope i could help you.